# Yii2 Advanced email template

Tags: email, yii2, components, html-email, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2 advanced version. I have configured email configuration in `common\config\main-local.php` as follows:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',           
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
             'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
             'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
             'username' => 'XXXXX',
             'password' => 'XXXXXX',
             'port' => '587',
             'encryption' => 'tls',
         ],
        ],
```

I have created one email component under `common\components\EmailComponent.php`
Which contains code for sending an email :

```
protected function sendEmail($email, $subject, $message, $options= array()) {
            $email = 'myemail@myemail.com';
           **$emailSend = Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' =>'layouts/html'],['content' => $message])**
                    ->setFrom(["myemail@myemail.com"])
                    ->setTo($email)
                    ->setSubject($subject);
        return $emailSend->send();
    }
```

I have created two layout files under

1) `common\mail\layouts\html.php`

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <table id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" height="411" width="600" style="font-family:arial; font-size:14px;">
            <tbody>      
<tr>
                **<td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #bc2744; height:1px">First</td>**
            </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                       <?php
                       echo $content;                   
                       ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                **<td colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #bc2744; height:1px">Second</td>**
            </tbody>
        </table>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

2) `common\mail\layouts\text.php`

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?=  $content; ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

When I fire an email from any section then I get an emails but it shows "First" text  Two times Then My content will come and then again it shows "Second" text Two times from email html.php file. 
I don't know why this is happening, I have searched a lot but no luck.

Comment: I am also stuck at it. If you have found the solution then please share.

Answer (score 1):

Change path of your templates:
`common\mail\layouts\html.php` to `common\mail\html.php` for example

Answer (score 0):

Try setting htmlBody

```
protected function sendEmail($email, $subject, $message, $options= array()) {

  $email = 'myemail@myemail.com';
  $emailSend = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
   ->setFrom('myemail@myemail.com')
   ->setTo($email)
   ->setSubject($subject)
   ->setHtmlBody($message);

   return $emailSend->send();
}
```

Comment: then it'll not take my email layout contents, like first & second text

Comment: but it's not taking default layout, so that I have used Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' =>'layouts/html'],

Comment: I'm sorry my suggestions are for test if you can solve the repeated .. sending of info.. when this work.. then look at the layout.. .. the layout

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('layouts/html', ['content' => $message])
->setFrom('sender@email.com')
->setTo("receiver@email.com")
->setSubject("subject")
->send();
```

You must have /common/mail/layouts/html.php

Comment: I think you have not read my question properly. Please read it again